# Laravel eloquent random query

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have this kind of eloquent query where I need to take random rows from a table, with a limit, but it returns wrong, when I use limit, then it pulls only one row, no matter what number I take in as a limit. And when I don't use limit it returns random number of rows. Don't know what I am missing. This is the code.

```
$questions = $query->whereRaw('RAND()')->take($limit)->get();
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is *$limit* set at?

Comment: I am taking limit from request, so it is not set to anything, but when I send a request with a limit of 10 I get only one row

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should have been using `orderByRaw`.

But there is a better solution, you can add this macro:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder;

Builder::macro('orderByRandom', function () {

    $randomFunctions = [
        'mysql'  => 'RAND()',
        'pgsql'  => 'RANDOM()',
        'sqlite' => 'RANDOM()',
        'sqlsrv' => 'NEWID()',
    ];

    $driver = $this->getConnection()->getDriverName();

    return $this->orderByRaw($randomFunctions[$driver]);
});
```

So you can do: `$query->orderByRandom()->take($limit)->get();`

Comment: I still only get one row, whenever I have some value in limit.

Comment: There is probably something else wrong in your code. Is `$limit` properly set? Does it work if you manually execute the query? Where does `$query` come from, what is applied to it previously?

Comment: Yes, something is obviously wrong with $limit, because when I set it manually, it executes correctly, I am taking $limit from request, and then apply it in the query

Comment: Ah, stupid mistake, I was sending request as an array, and then $limit was null, so that's why it didn't work, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You are using RAND in your where, it shout be in the ORDER BY

```
$questions = $query->orderByRaw('RAND()')->take($limit)->get();
```

Comment: this is still returning the same